# Is frontend or backend a better place to do some manipulation on submitted form data?

Tags: html, rest, web-applications, web

I am developing a qr code generator. Once the users fills the form to generate any type of QR code(sms, email, vcard, etc), the data is to be converted into a standard format that can be recognized by a qrcode scanner. Eg mailto:name@email.com. Now my question is whether to do this conversion on frontend or backend.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, for both security and organization it is better to process forms on the back end (server side) rather than the front end (client side).